# Conditional regular expressions in stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm wondering how to implement a conditional regular expression in R.  It seems that this can be implemented in PERL:

```
?(if)then|else
```

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement this in R.  As a simple example, let's say I have the following strings:

```
c('abcabd', 'abcabe')
```

I would like the regular expression to match `"bd"` if it is there and `"bc"` otherwise, then replace it with `"zz"`.  Thus, I would like the strings above to be:

```
c('abcazz', 'azzabe')
```

I have tried this using both `sub` and `str_replace` neither of which seem to work.  It seems that my syntax might be wrong in `sub`:

```
sub('b(?(?=d)d|c)', 'zz', c('abcabe','abcabd'), perl=TRUE)
[1] "azzabe" "azzabd"
```

The logic is "match b, if followed by d match d, otherwise match c".  With `str_replace`, I get errors :

```
str_replace(c('abcabe','abcabd'), regex('b(?(?=d)d|c)'), 'zz')
Error in stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
Use of regexp feature that is not yet implemented. (U_REGEX_UNIMPLEMENTED)
```

I primarily use `stringr` so would prefer a solution using `str_replace` but open to solutions using `sub`.

Comment: In posted answer I used `sub()` which you may convert to `str_replace`: `str_replace(c('abcabe','abcabd'), regex('^(.*)bd|bc'), '\\1zz')`

Comment: Thanks!  I am still working through understanding the conditional regex you posted, but regarding this alternative, is the reason this works that regex always prefers the greedier option, ie. whatever matches the longest string?

Comment: Regex engine tries first path if it fails tries next immediate available path. In `^(.*)bd` engine goes through all characters, looking for `bd` if it exists engine won't try the other side of alternation (already found a match, satisfied) but if it fails it goes for `bc`. This causes engine not to miss a chance to match a `bd` that comes before a `bc` too.

Comment: Great, I think I understand now.  I believe what is happening is that the regex searches character-by-character for a match, using the order of the alternation `|` to determine priority, hence why `^(.*)bd|bc` works but `bd|bc` does not.

Comment: `bd|bc` which is a fancy way to say `b[cd]` (but order is important) makes engine to have 2 immediate choice in each step. If next two characters are not `bd` it tries for `bc` and stops as soon as it finds a match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost near but you should have conditional pattern true assertion in each step:

```
(?(?=.*bd)bd|bc)
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/4crMHj)

You don't even need conditional regex:

```
^(.*)bd|bc
```

R code:

```
sub('^(.*)bd|bc', '\\1zz', c('abcabe','abcabd'))
```

Comment: The conditional regex you suggested still gives the "U_REGEX_IMPLEMENTED" error. eg, I did type ```str_detect('abcabe', '(?(?=.*bd)bd|bc)')``` and got that error

Comment: @pendermath It seems that `str_detect()` regular expressions is not perl compatible. It implements ICU which doesn't support conditional statements. To be able to use this regex you probably need to go for [`grepl()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/grep) which also supports perl through a flag.

Comment: Makes sense. Thx!